# Exchange server- send email with mail-type html - corrupted links

Tags: php, email, character-encoding, exchange-server, url-encoding

I am using CodeIgniter library to send emails from my windows exchange server.
But When I tried to send html type email, and this email includes links, then the received email is corrupted!

sent email:

http://domain.x.io/researchapp/admin/reviewerspage1?email=abcdefg@gmail.com&phase=1&id=40

recieved email:

http://domain.x.io/researchapp/admin/reviewerspage1?email=abcdefg@gmail=.com&phase=1&id=40

//Code:

```
    $this->load->library('email');
    $this->email->clear();
    $this->email->initialize(array(
        'protocol' => 'smtp',
                        'smtp_host' => 'srv.domain.x.io',
                        'mailtype' => 'html',
                        'smtp_port' => 25,
                        'crlf' => "\n",
                        'newline' => "\r\n"
                        ));
    $this->email->to('xx@gmail.com');
    $this->email->from('no-reply@domain.x.io', 'subject');
    $this->email->subject('subject' );
    $this->email->message('http://domain.x.io/researchapp/admin/reviewerspage1?email=abcdefg@gmail.com&phase=1&id=40'  );
    $this->email->send();
    echo $this->email->print_debugger();
```

Although I used the gmail server and it worked fine to send links successfully.

Comment: Please show us the code you are using

Comment: I have edited the question